# Is DTO a better practice, or using service when you can not change DB?

Tags: java, spring, dto

I learned that DTO is the mapping between Data Layer and View Layer, and people have different opinions about use DTO or not. I have looked around this topic for a while, but I am still confusing. So, I created this topic to look for some advice. 
I am trying to re-writing a old application. The only unchanged thing is DB. (Well, it is changed as well. New columns and new tables are added.) But all back-end, front-end code will be rewritten.

Since DB is remained, and UI changed a lot. So, there are many mismatch between DB and UI. e.g. columns from one table may be put to different UI places, and one UI page may need data from multiple tables.
In this case, I think I should create a DTO layer to mapping the Data Layer with View Layer.

Can someone share experiences or better options about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disconnecting the view to the data layer may seem extra work, extra testing, more code etc. etc. but its paid for upfront and saves pain to come. Its most obvious when you see questions of people who has issues saving their view model directly to the DB. They _are_ separate irregardless of how close the data they contain are. 

The more sensible layers of separation between data there area the easier is it to change models, which is really what this is about.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe agree. I think the pain at the beginning is better than struggle with it everyday.

Comment: tools like mapstruct can greatly help avoid issues when it comes to mapping java beans to others.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Thank you. I was looking at ModelMapper. I did not know MapStruct before. Do you have experience for both？

Comment: I do not. Mapstruct uses an annotation processor to generate the classes for mapping e.g. its compile time. It _looks_ like modelmapper is reflection based at runtime.